# Does order matter in chained divisions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been dealing with some equations and I've got a bit of a problem. The equation as follows.
$$t=\frac S{(V_f+V_i)/2}$$
I couldn't quite simplify it because on one hand I've got multiplication by the reciprocal rule which states that 
$$t=\frac S1×\frac2{V_f+V_i}=\frac{2S}{V_f+V_i}$$
and on the other hand I've got the order of operations stating that
$$a/b/c =\frac a{bc}$$
which leads me to
$$t=\frac S{2(V_f+V_i)}$$
I'm sure I'm missing something here, but I can't quite get my head around it. Help would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first interpretation is correct:
$$t=\frac{2S}{V_f+V_i}$$
When dealing with chained multiplications and divisions the order does matter; without parentheses an expression is evaluated *left to right*. So $a/b/c$ evaluates as $(a/b)/c$, which can be simplified to $\frac a{bc}$ as you have pointed out in the second interpretation. However, the given expression is of the form $a/(b/c)$, which is not equivalent to $(a/b)/c$ and simplifies to the different result of $\frac{ac}b$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, but I wonder how come I've never heard of it in a class or somewhere else... Maybe I just wasn't paying attention. The division tends to be trickier than multiplication and it's kinda annoying... Oh, well... The intuition for that is important.

Answer (score 0):

Order matters. For example, $2/(2/3)=3$ while $(2/2)/3=1/3$. In your rule, $a/b/c$ is a short notation for
$$(a/b)/c=\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c}$$
which differs from
$$a/(b/c)=\frac{a}{\frac{b}{c}}$$
which is the form of your original expression. Hence you cannot apply $a/b/c=\frac{a}{bc}$ to the original formula, because it is not the form of the original formula.